# Strip all characters after the final dash in a string in Python, and test if numeric?

Tags: python, string, numeric

If I have a string:

```
string = 'this-is-a-string-125'
```

How can I grab the last set of characters after the dash and check if they are digits?

Comment: I didn't downvote, however, if you "grab the last set of numbers" then they must be numeric, yes? Otherwise, they wouldn't be numbers ;)

Comment: @Hamish -- you're right, thanks. Text updated to clarify.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to verify that they are actually digits, you can do

```
x.rsplit('-', 1)[1].isdigit()
```

"Numeric" is a more general criteria that could be interpreted different ways.  For instance "12.87" is numeric in some sense, but not all the characters are digits.

You can do `int(x.rsplit('-', 1)[1])` to see if the string can be interpreted as a integer, or `float(x.rsplit('-', 1)[1])` to see if it can be interpreted as a float.  (These will raise a ValueError if the string isn't numeric in the appropriate sense, so you can catch that exception and do whatever you need to do if it's not numeric.)

Answer (score 5):

```
s = 'this-is-a-string-125'.split('-')[-1].isdigit()
```

We split the string by dash (`'-'`) which gives a list of substrings (see [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)). We then take the last one (`[-1]`) and we verify that that string contains only digits ([`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)):

```
>>> 'this-is-a-string-125'.split('-')
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string', '125']
>>> 'this-is-a-string-125'.split('-')[-1]
'125'
>>> 'this-is-a-string-125'.split('-')[-1].isdigit()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Nobody knows about [partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) or [rpartition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
text.rpartition("-")[-1].isdigit()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
str.split('-')[-1].isdigit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple regex can do both the stripping and checking:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'this-is-a-string-125'
>>> m = re.search(r'-(\d+)$', s)
>>> m.group(1)
'125'
>>>  s[:m.start()] # gives you what was stripped away.
'this-is-a-string'
```

Match object `m` will be `None` if the string lacks a dash character followed by one or more digits at the end.